# Is there a way to overwrite pipe on linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I was wondering if there is a way to replace the default behavior of the `|` command in bash with a custom command. I would like overwrite the pipe command.

This is a strictly technical and theoretical question. A random use case would be logging each time a pipe was used.

For instance :

```
echo "foo" |grep o
```

Would return :

f**oo**

But will also save `echo "foo"` + timestamp into a `pipe.log` log file

Comment: This sounds like a headache you really don't wanna go through

Comment: The `|` symbol is not a command so it can't be overridden by e.g. a shell function. You could still override `grep` with a function that saved the output to a file.

Comment: For bash, I suggest you better look into `trap '...' DEBUG` and `shopt -s extdebug`. That combo allows you to log, change or just skip any command before being run.

Comment: At a practical level, every process that used bash and a pipe would be logging to the same file (including a bunch of system and background processes), but you want to log every line to one file with no indication of which process was involved. Also, forget "line": pipes are used for bulk binary data too.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is not a command. So that is not possible.

But you might be able to simulate what you want by using `history` and abusing $PS1:

```
PS1="$PS1"'`(date;history | tail -n1 | perl -ne "s/\|.*// and print") >> ~/pipe.log`'
```